# How can I keep the whitespace between floated left/right divs empty?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having a problem best illustrated by the following minimal example.

```css
div.left {
  float: left;
}

div.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
<div>underneath</div>
```

When I view this HTML in Chrome, 'underneath' appears between '`left`' and '`right`', but I would like it to be beneath, on a new line. What should I do to best implement this? Thanks.

Comment: it is a little unclear because you already have it underneath. You may want `underneat` div inside the first div where are `.left` and `.right`

Comment: Add a class to the `div` containing "underneath" with the rule `clear: both;`.

Comment: Thanks, `clear: both;` fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the elements are removed from the normal flow which allows the 'underneath' to rise up into that position. The way to fix that is to add `clear:both` to the underneath's div. This means no floated elements can be to the right or left of that individual div.

[See this.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#propdef-clear)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div>
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div>underneath</div>
```

CSS

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to add the extra element?

Comment: But you would get exactly the same result by adding `.clear` to the `div` containing "underneath", there's no need for the extra markup.